# Why do the same bans often occur in ranked play at Bronze and Silver ELO?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've noticed that in Bronze and Silver ELO (Specifically 1100-1400), certain champions are almost always banned. These include

- Amumu [tank]
- Malphite [tank]
- Shen [tank]
- Blitzcrank

and sometimes

- Singed [tank]
- Darius
- Diana
- Katarina
- Morgana

Why is it that these champions are more likely to be banned than others? Also, why are tanks often banned in ranked play? I don't believe it's because the champion is overpowered.

This thread may be closed, due to [Why are characters banned in tournament play for DotA-likes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28259/why-are-characters-banned-in-tournament-play-for-dota-likes) but I really want to be more specific right now.

Also, these bans aren't very common in professional level play, so why are these champions so often banned at the 1100-1400 ELO? Please note I'm talking about a specific ELO so the answer would be different than the link above.

Comment: Most of the banned champions here are incredibly disruptive in team-fights. Players at this level might not know when to fight, when to back out, or how to position themselves properly.

Answer (score 4):

1100-1400 ELO is a point where players aren't too familiar with the more difficult concepts of the game yet.

If Amumu isn't banned, who is going to kill him? In a coordinated and balanced teamfight, it's highly unlikely anyone but the ranged AD is able to effectively stop him. (Tanks are usually banned because they are harder to kill.) Many players may not know how to position themselves, or to stay alive so these hard to kill champions may be considered overpowered at this ELO.

Who wants to chase Singed through a mile of poison gas? Who wants to be hit into the air by a scary piece of rock? A lack of competency is most likely present at this ELO so therefore certain champions are able to take advantage of this and contribute more to the team.

At professional levels, more strategy definitely occurs during champion selection, but at this specific ELO which most of LoL's ranked players are in, these bans occur often due to the reasons above.

Comment: Some people have asked me this and I looked into it a bit more to find a logical answer so I answered it myself.

Answer (score 2):

This are very strong picks if you don't have good skillset in team. If you play Solo Q and your team communication sucks you must consider such bans...

---

**Amumu**, **Malphite**, **Morgana** - AoE ultimate with Crowd Control effects.

**Blitzcrank**, **Malphite**, **Singed** - Great initiation skills that can't be easy stopped.

---

**Shen** - Be in every important teamfight like having *Teleport*

---

**Darius**, **Katarina** - Skills that are refreshed after kill/assist

Comment: can't be easy stopped at bronze-silver, that is xD thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The higher elo players ban champions for particular reasons in mind.  These eventually traverse down to lower elo games where everyone is seeing these champions banned and perhaps **do not even know why.**

Blitzcrank is banned frequently because of his **Q, E, R combo.**  Yet if blitz crank misses his Q he is quite useless until it comes up and this is especially evident when he is supporting bot lane in the early game.  When blitz miss his Q, the other team then can harass and shut down the other side completely until it is back up.

*However*, these are referred to as "overpowered" or "cheap" champions because they can catch a player off guard and simply put, **wreck them**.

Another reason all the same champs are banned is because, **people will complain and blame losing the game on you**. (If you are losing, of course)